# React native default RTL support on multi language app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-i18next

I have two languages react native app en and ar. App default language is ar. I have override native code to set language layout to rtl. Also I am using react-native-restart for switch the language.

Initally first page load it's working fine and loaded arabic as default language and layout rtl. When I switch the language to en it's not working and layout remain same rtl. It didn't forceRTL to false after restart application.

When I remove forceRTL from native code than it's working fine if default language is en but not working if set default language is ar.

How can I switch the language as default ar language?

i18n.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import en from "../lang/en.json";
import ar from "../lang/ar.json";
import { I18nManager } from "react-native";

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
compatibilityJSON: "v3",
lng: I18nManager.isRTL ? "ar" : "en",
fallbackLng: I18nManager.isRTL ? "ar" : "en",
resources: {
en: en,
ar: ar,
},
interpolation: {
escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
},
});

export default i18n;
```

index.js

```
const changeDirection = (value) => {
I18nManager.forceRTL(value);
RNRestart.Restart();
};


{I18nManager.isRTL ? (
    <ButtonTypeA
      clickEvent={() => {
        changeDirection(false);
      }}
      title={"EN"}
    />
  ) : (
    <ButtonTypeA
      clickEvent={() => {
        changeDirection(true);
      }}
      title={"AR"}
    />
  )}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@OverRide
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(this,true);
sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(this, true);
}
```

**Updated:**

I have resolved it by store language using AsyncStorage and restart app on first load. As default app language is AR so forceRTL didn't work if set in MainActivity.java file. Find updated code as below for your reference.

MainActivity.java  -  remove forceRTL

```
@OverRide
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
//sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(this,true);
sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(this, true);
}
```

_layout.js -  On first load store language and restart app

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const Layout = () => {
  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    await checkFirstLaunch();
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

  // check if app first launch than set check rtl
  const checkFirstLaunch = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem("@lang").then((value) => {
        if (value === null) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem("@lang", "ar");
          I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
          I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
          RNRestart.Restart();
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      //saving error
    }
  };

  return (
  );
export default Layout;
```

i18n.js

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const languageDetector = {
  type: "languageDetector",
  async: true, // async detection
  detect: (callback) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("@lang").then((lng) => {
      if (lng === null) {
        callback("ar");
      } else {
        callback(lng);
      }
    });
  },
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    compatibilityJSON: "v3",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    resources: {
      en: en,
      ar: ar,
    },
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

index.js

```
const changeLanguage = (value) => {
i18n
  .changeLanguage(value)
  .then(() => {
    const isLangRTL = value === "ar";
    AsyncStorage.setItem("@lang", value);

    if (isLangRTL !== I18nManager.isRTL) {
      I18nManager.allowRTL(isLangRTL);
      I18nManager.forceRTL(isLangRTL);
      RNRestart.Restart();
    }

    setLocale(value);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

{I18nManager.isRTL ? (
    <ButtonTypeA
      clickEvent={() => {
        changeLanguage("en");
      }}
      title={"EN"}
    />
  ) : (
    <ButtonTypeA
      clickEvent={() => {
        changeLanguage("ar");
      }}
      title={"AR"}
    />
  )}
```